# Option on $ \left( \int_0^T dW_t \right)^2$

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus

Silly question, but how would you actually price
$$
E_0 \left(  \left( \int_0^T dW_t \right)^2  - K \right)_+ 
$$
where $dW_t$ are standard Brownian motions. Is there a closed form analytical solution?

Comment: Isn’t $\int_0^T dW_t$ simply equal to $W_T$? I expect you would obtain a closed form solution similar to the CIR model (chi squared distribution)?

Comment: @KeSchn You are right of course :) My question *is* silly, brain fart.. I was actually wondering how to price $(( \int_0^T \alpha_t dW_t)^2 - K)_+$ with $\alpha_t$ some other stochastic process, but wanted to look at a simplified situation first. I may have simplified too much though!